# What is the value of an undefined parameter?

Tags: function

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of the code below:

```
function multiplier(factor){
    return number => number * factor;
}

let twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
```

At the function call *multiplier(2)*, the value of 2 is returned to the binding *twice*, which is 2, but how so?  This implies that the return statement would evaluate to *1 * 2*, but the parameter *number* was never assigned a value.  I was expecting *undefined * 2*, instead which would return undefined.  Why is the parameter *number* assigned a value of 1?

Answer (score 1):

What `let twice = multiplier(2);` does is stored following function in `twice` variable

```
function(number) {
 // factor variable value was set here
 return number * 2;
}
```

When you called

```
console.log(twice(5));
```

It runs function stored in twice variable as following

```
function(5) {
  return 5 * 2;
}
```

Hence you got **10** on console.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now.  What was returned to the initial call was an anonymous function, (number) => number * 2.  The was the value binded to twice from that initial call. 

The second call now passes the argument 5 to that stored anonymous function as (5) => 5 *2, which is 10.  I get it now.  

I initially saw it in my head as number = number * factor not realizing that I had yet to grasp that I was actually seeing function notation.